# Aspect Fit Background Color Spilling Over

Tags: ios, objective-c, aspect-fit

I need the image to always aspect Fit - as I need to to retain it's shape within any given frame, however, when I stick a background color on the image it spills over, no matter what I seem to do. Any help?

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.nonScoreBasedView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.nonScoreBasedView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.nonScoreBasedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `UIImageView` is the exact same ratio as the image at all times?

Comment: No it isn't - do you think this is the only way to do that?

Comment: With your current setup it looks that way - you could consider creating an object with a background colour view that is a few pixels smaller than the image view on top of it.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that then